# remove certain special characters from Text

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

Hey guys I am making a project on PhantomJS where I read source code of some webpages and i extract some info i need from there. I successfully finished the work just one issue I am facing right now.
I have a text that have inside it special characters I need to get rid off. in my case I have :

```
Avenue de Citeaux 22<br><br>1348 Louvain-la-Neuve
```

that "<><>" i need to get rid off, I am using :

```
str.replace('<br><br>','')
```

but its not working ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.replace(/<br>/g, "")` (regular expression with global search flag enabled, to replace all occurences).

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
str = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

I've just realised, str.replace() RETURNS the value, not replaces it. Try the above.